# How to load (replace) an external page by the current (no inside a div)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am building my first web application in jsp, i think that the desing could be better, however, it Works. What I want is to load an external page but no wrapped it inside a div element. Let me explain it:

My main page, it has two empty divs, and the content for both of them is loaded by load Jquery function.

wsIndex.jsp

```
    <html>
        <script>            
        $(document).ready(function() {                  
            $('#divWSInputForm').load('wsInputForm.jsp');
            $('#divWSInputDataTable').load('wsInputDataTable.jsp');
        })            
        </script>

        <div id="divWSInputForm"></div>
        <div id="divWSInputDataTable"></div>
 </html>
```

The following is the content of the first div (divWSInputForm). It has a form with one input field and a button. Also it has an Ajax Jquery event for the button.

wsInputForm.jsp

```
<html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#sbmsave').click(function(event){
    $.post(
            'wsSave.jsp',
            {itxtcode:$('#itxtcode').val()},            
            function(responseText){
                $('#divWSInputDataTable').html(responseText);
                ...
            }
    );
} );    

})  
</script> 

<form id="rendered-form" method="post" >
<input name="itxtcode" id="itxtcode" type="text">
.. other inputs ..
<button name="sbmsave" id="sbmsave" type="button" >Save</button>
</form>
</html>
```

The following is the content of the second div (divWSInputDataTable). Inside I request and retrieve some data from Oracle DataBase, then I build a table with this data.

wsInputDataTable.jsp

```
<html>
<%
// Connect to Oracle and retrieve data into a rs (ResultSet)
%>

<table id="workshops" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<th>Code</th>
...
</thead>    

<tbody>
<%
while (rs.next()) {
%>
<tr>
<td><%= rs.getString(1) %></td>
...
</tr>       
<%}%>
</tbody>

</table>
</html>
```

This is the jsp page which is called from wsInputForm.jsp (sbmsave) through Ajax post.

wsSave.jsp

```
   <%       
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    Connection conn = ds.connect();
    CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call Pkg_WorkShop.f_insertWorkShop(?)}");
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
    cstmt.setString(2, request.getParameter("itxtcode").toString());
    cstmt.execute();        
    %>
    <html >
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {              
        $('#cont').load('wsInputDataTable.jsp');            
    })
    </script>
    <div id="cont"></div>
```

Im no sure, but I suppose that every time I click on sbmsave button, the content of wsInputDataTable.jsp is loaded inside a div (id="cont"). So, if it is true, after "X" clicks, my current page will have "X" div's elements one inside another. isnt it?. It is something i would like to fix.

What I would like to know is exist another way to load the content of external page, but no inside a div element. Just load and replace the content of the current page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: javascript in ajax loaded pages don't run the way you may expect them to. The javascript might run too early, or it might not run at all, depending on the method you use to insert it. your usage of .ready() won't help you after the initial page load.

Comment: You should remove the `<html>` tags from the HTML that's going to end up inside the `<div>`s. As for the script parts, one way is to have a `<script id="ajaxscript"></script>` in your wrapper document, then change its `src` to the code you want to insert after you've load the inner div content. That way the JavaScript is executed, and at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out by using jquery load on wsSave.jsp and retrieve the response in the div from the main jsp. (I did not know that these elements can be acceded from an external jsp)

```
<script>
$('#divWSInputDataTable').load('wsInputDataTable.jsp');
</script>
```